# 'The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed'

Tags: entity-framework

New to EF framework and I am just trying to get my bearings. I am simply trying to use user input to pull up a record in a db.

```
public class DataController : Controller
{

// GET: /Data/

    // /Data/GetTest
    // Test endpoint
    // Works 
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetTest()
    {
        test t = null;
        using (Database1Entities context1  = new Database1Entities()) 
        {
            t = context1.tests.OrderByDescending(a => a.Id).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        JsonResult ret = new JsonResult { Data = t, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        return ret;
    }

    //This is the problem controller

    public JsonResult GetDataWithInput(test t) //test is a table with Id
    {                                          //and test1 fields

        using (Database1Entities context2 = new Database1Entities()) {
            var r = context2.tests.Where(a => a.test1.Equals(t.test1) && a.Id.Equals(t.Id));
            JsonResult ret = new JsonResult { Data = r, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
            return ret;
        }

    }

}
```

The /Data/GetTest works fine. This was the first testing endpoint and had no issues there. However, when I added user input to get the correct record of from the tests table on /Data/GetDataWithInput , I was hit with the error that the DbContext has been disposed.

Comment: Try with `Data = r.ToList()`

Comment: This worked, thank you @haim770

Answer (score 0):

Your `Database1Entities` context is disposed before the result is actually read from the database.

When using EF the different LINQ queries (`Where()`, `Take()` etc.) only build up a SQL statement that is executed as soon as the results are enumerated (for example when they are being displayed or serialized). This is called *materialization* of a LINQ query.

In your case the web framework tries to serialize the result list, which triggers the execution of the constructed SQL statement. But by the time that happens the `DbContext` has already been disposed.

You can force the materialization of a LINQ query by calling `ToList()` on it.

Try calling `ToList()` on `r`:

```
public JsonResult GetDataWithInput(test t)
{
    using (Database1Entities context2 = new Database1Entities()) {
        ...
        JsonResult ret = new JsonResult { 
            // Note the ToList() here.
            Data = r.ToList(), 
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By the time MVC framework gets around to actually turning this object into JSON, your DBContext has gone out of scope.

You need to call ToList() on your IQueryable to finalize the query and actually get results from the DB.

I've modified your code below to call ToList()

```
  using (Database1Entities context2 = new Database1Entities()) {
        var r = context2.tests.Where(a => a.test1.Equals(t.test1) && a.Id.Equals(t.Id));
        JsonResult ret = new JsonResult { Data = r.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        return ret;
    }
```